# Python: SQL query results to table

Tags: python

I have the results for a SQL query in Python and I would like to convert this into a table with the appropriate data formats.

The results now:

```
(datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 13, 0, 0), Decimal('6.16'), Decimal('5.95'), Decimal('4.05')),
```

I would like the results to be:

```
13/01/14, 6.16, 5.95, 4.05
```

I have tried:

```
Data = list(conn.execute(# some query));
Stuff = [];
for row in Data:
Stuff.append([i for i in zip(time.strftime("%d %m %Y", row['day'].timetuple()), float(row['col1']), float(row['col2']), float(row['col3']))]);
```

But this seems to only zip by 1 character and not each element separated by ','. Is there a way to zip by delimiter? Or any alternative implementation to get the desired result.

**EDIT**

The solution previously suggested creates a list with [day, a1, a2, a3] i.e. n x 1 table vs n x 4 table i.e. day, a1, a2, a3 which is required. Is there any way to do this using zip or something similar?

Comment: what does `conn.execute` retuen before you cast it to a list?

Comment: Could you post your full code? It looks like you might be using some optional features such as `DictCursor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Stuff = []
for row in Data:
    Stuff.append([i for i in [row['day'], float(row['a1']), float(row['a2']), float(row['a3'])]]);
```

Comment: `[i for i in [row['day'], float(row['a1']), float(row['a2']), float(row['a3'])]]` this is equivalent (albeit slower) to just `[row['day'], float(row['a1']), float(row['a2']), float(row['a3'])]` which is what I proposed in my solution. If one works, then the other should also work

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `zip`. `zip` takes multiple lists and interleaves them

```
>>> zip('abc', '123')
[('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')]
```

Just append the data straight to your `Stuff` list

```
Data = list(conn.execute(# some query));
Stuff = [];
for row in Data:
    Stuff.append([time.strftime("%d %m %Y", row['day'].timetuple()), float(row['col1']), float(row['col2']), float(row['col3'])])
```

Comment: Yields an n x 1 array whereas a n x 4 array is required.

Comment: than your query returns just one row

Comment: @Blackholify which Python MySQL library are you using?

Comment: @PeterGibson using psycopg2 (postgresql). I've got the solution so it's fine now. Thanks